# ¿Usar coma antes de abrir interrogante?

Tags: gramática, puntuación

¿Cuál de estos dos ejemplos es correcto?

- Hey, ¿Quieres venir a comer?
- Hey ¿Quieres venir a comer?

Leyendo libros me he encontrado con ambos tipos por lo que tengo un lío de cuándo se ha de usar la coma y cuándo no, al abrir interrogación.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Debe utilizarse una coma y, puesto que la coma no cierra la oración, la pregunta debe comenzar con minúscula:

- Hey/Ey, ¿**quieres** venir a comer?

Nota: la interjección "hey" se considera un americanismo (ver [hey/ey](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/ey-hey/)). En España, parece preferirse "ey" o "eh" como un modo de llamar la atención.

Comment: No dudes en hacer un rollback si no quedó bien.

Answer (score 3):

Se debe usar la coma, pero no porque detrás venga una interrogación, sino porque estás usando "eh" como un vocativo. Cuando se usan palabras para apelar a otras personas, se debe poner una coma detrás. Véase el siguiente ejemplo:

> ¡Pepe viene ya!

Con esta frase estamos diciendo a todo el mundo que Pepe viene de camino.

> ¡Pepe, viene ya!

Con esta otra decimos a Pepe que otra persona viene de camino. El uso de la coma ha cambiado completamente el sentido de la oración, dado que en la primera se usa "Pepe" como sujeto de la misma, y en la segunda tiene un uso vocativo, haciendo que el sujeto de "viene ya" sea una tercera persona indeterminada.

Por tanto, dado que en el ejemplo usas "eh" (no "hey" o "ey") como vocativo para llamar la atención de la persona a quien te diriges, debes poner la coma detrás. Puedes comprobar este uso en el párrafo 1.2.3 del artículo *[coma<sup>1</sup>](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=coma)* del DPD.

Por tanto, tu frase quedaría así:

> Pepe/eh/oye, ¿quieres venir a comer?

Existen otros casos en los que no es necesario usar la coma, pero seguramente irían sin vocativo, como en este ejemplo:

> Pero entonces Pepe ¿por qué no viene?